# When using a static method, does the class every get instantiated?

Tags: java, static

Say I have a static method increment:

```
public class StaticTest {
    private static int no = 0;

    public static void increment()
    {
        no++;
    }
}
```

When I call increment using the `StaticTest.increment()` syntax, does the class ever get instantiated? What if no object of that type exists on the heap already?

Comment: The phrase "class of that type" makes me think you've misunderstood something fundamental about classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When I call increment using the `StaticTest.increment()` syntax, does the class ever get instantiated?

The *class*, itself, is loaded (by the classloader), if it isn't already loaded. If it's already loaded, it is not loaded a second time. No instances of the class (objects of that class's type) are created, because you haven't created any.

Assuming all of the code that calls `StaticTest.increment()` is using the same classloader (which is normally the case), it doesn't matter how many different bits of code call that static method, just a single copy of the class is used. They all share it. E.g.:

```
// Some bit of code somewhere
StaticTest.increment();

// Another bit of code somewhere else
StaticTest.increment();

// A third bit of code in yet another place
StaticTest.increment();
```

Once all of those have run, the `no` private static member in `StaticTest` has the value `3`.

> What if no class of that type exists on the heap already?

Then then classloader loads it.

---

Contrast that code with this (no `static`s):

```
public class NonStaticTest {
    private int no = 0;

    public void increment()
    {
        no++;
    }

    public int getNo() // So we can see the results
    {
        return no;
    }
}
```

Now, we can't do this:

```
NonStaticTest.increment(); // WRONG, fails with error saying `increment` is not static
```

We do this instead:

```
NonStaticTest instance = new NonStaticTest();
instance.increment();
System.out.println(instance.getNo()); // "1"
```

The *first* time code does that, the `NonStaticTest` class is loaded by the classloader. Then, the `new NonStaticTest()` expression creates an *instance* of the class, which has a `no` member. The *second* time code does that, `NonStaticTest` has already been loaded, so it's not loaded again. Then the `new NonStaticTest()` expression creates a second *instance* of the class.

If we had three bits of code all doing the above, each of them would see "1", because `no` is specific to an *instance* of the class rather than being attached to the class itself.

Answer (score 2):

You have to clearly differentiate between 2 things:

- classes, which are sort of "custom types" (I'm simplifying here)
- objects, which are instances of these classes

Classes are loaded once by the classloader, whereas objects of a class are created each time you call `new ClassName()` (if the class is called `ClassName`).

Now, back to your problem: the use of the `static` keyword makes your declarations independant of any *instance* (object) of your class.

Therefore, when you use `StaticTest.increment()`, **no object of the class `StaticTest` is created** (and no object is needed).

Answer (score 1):

You instantiate an instance with `new StaticTest` and unless you created one of those, you haven't created an instance.